# enable text in block oracle form

Tags: oracle, textbox, block, oracleforms

I have a problem to enable text in a block oracle form.
how to enable field text qty_actual in a block when barcode = part number then enable qty_actual
help me please.

[image]

code :

```
set_block_property('part_lokases',default_where,'part_part_no =||':barcode.txtb');
go_block('part_lokases');
execute_query;
set_block_property('part_lokases',default_where,'');
go_item('part_lokases.qty_actual');
set_item_property('part_lokases.qty_actual',ENABLED,PROPERTY_TRUE);
```

Comment: First of all, there's a logical issue for the order of the last two lines of your code. Those should be replaced, enable the item firstly, and then send the cursor on it. ( *Indeed, `set_item_property` seems to be replaced with `set_item_instance_property` for your case as @littlefoot already told* ).

Answer (score 2):

As it is a tabular form, you'll have to use `SET_ITEM_INSTANCE_PROPERTY` built-in procedure. Something like this:

```
if :tabular_block.par_number = :barcode.part_number then
   set_item_instance_property('tabular_block.qty_actual', current_record, insert_allowed, property_true);
   set_item_instance_property('tabular_block.qty_actual', current_record, update_allowed, property_true);
else
   set_item_instance_property('tabular_block.qty_actual', current_record, insert_allowed, property_false);
   set_item_instance_property('tabular_block.qty_actual', current_record, update_allowed, property_false);
end if;
```

Comment: thank you @Littlefoot, but I need to enable qty_actual textbox(in specific field like ex. picture) in part_lokases block if barcode.txtb = part_lokases.part_part_no

Comment: Well, that's what I said, didn't I? Though, I didn't know block names at the time I wrote the answer, but - you should be able to fix it yourself. The bottom line is: use SET_ITEM_**INSTANCE**_PROPERTY, not SET_ITEM_PROPERTY.